Difference-in-Differences with Multiple Time Periods
For my master thesis, I want to estimate the effect that replications have on the citations of a paper. For this, I wanted to make a comparison between the citations of papers that were once replicated versus papers that were not.
My supervisor told me that a more appropriate model would be a staggered difference-in-differences (DiD), with a Poisson regression, given the nature of my dependent variable (citations is a non-negative count number). However, he told me to try an initial "simple" DiD to see the results, even if they could be biased.
In my data set I have around 80 papers that were replicated at different points in time (therefore my treatment group), and 160 that were never replicated (control group). To ensure comparability, I took only empirical papers that were published in the same journals, volumes, issues, and about the same topics or JEL code. Here is a snippet:

So, if we look at a simple DiD equation, and apply it to my data, this is what I would like to estimate:
$$
citations_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 replicated_i + \beta_2 time_t + \beta_3 (replicated_i \times time_t) + \varphi X_{it} + u_{it},
$$
where $replicated_i$ is the treatment dummy (1 if replicated, 0 if never replicated), and $time_t$ is the time dummy (before = 0 and after = 1).
The issue I see here is that there is no "after" for my control group, since those papers were never replicated, and I cannot take the "after" of a single treated paper because all have different treatment years (some repeat but in general it's 15 different years). Because of this, the construction of my time dummy makes the variable $\text{d_time}$ in the data frame always 0 for my control group (replicated = 0).
If I run such a model, my interaction term gets omitted because of perfect collinearity between the interaction term and the time dummy.
What am I missing here?
Now, I know this is the "basic" DiD model, which may lead to some specification issues because of the nature of my data. But I want to implement it before trying any other more advanced method. Does anybody have suggestions?
I am trying to understand the Callaway & Sant'Anna paper regarding staggered DiD, but I'm having issues understanding the implementation and interpretation of the model. Because, from what I understand, each treated paper could act as a control paper, if it was treated after another one (e.g., a replicated paper in 2015 could act as a control paper for a paper replicated in 2010, and so on). However, I wanted to compare only NEVER-replicated papers with replicated ones, therefore I'm unsure whether this is the best approach).

Welcome. Do you care about the citations of the newly replicated paper, or the old (original) publication? What about articles with dozens of replications?

I'm not sure if I understand you question. But I care about the citations of the papers that were replicated in general (either if the were replicated 10 years ago, or 3 years ago).

And why wouldn’t there be an “after” period for the non-replicated papers? Aren’t you assessing citations over time for all papers?

Because each paper that was replicated (aka, received treatment), was replicated in different years. There is no clear cutt-off (before-after). If you look at the snippet of the dataset, those never-replicated papers, have no such thing as a rep_year, since they were never replicated. So when creating my time dummy (before-after), those papers will always be 0. BEcause my time dummy I create something like: If year>rep_year, then 1, otherwise 0

You cannot estimate the "canonical" difference-in-differences (DiD) equation with replication patterns that start at different times for different units. The standard interaction term is not estimable because there is no single "after" period. In fact, we have many "post-treatment" periods. You need to define the treatment variable in a different way. The generalization of the basic  DiD equation would look something like the following:
$$
\text{log}(citations_{it}) = \gamma_i + \tau_t + \delta replicated_{it} + \beta X_{it}
$$
where we regress the "count" of citations for paper $i$ in year $t$ on paper fixed effects $\gamma_i$, year fixed effects $\lambda_t$, and single treatment variable $replicated_{it}$. Here, $X_{it}$ simply denotes a control vector of paper characteristics that vary over time, if any. I don't know what $u_{it}$ denotes in your post. If it's the error term, then it does not exist in a Poisson model; simply drop it. Modeling citations over time as a Poisson process seems appropriate, though I don't have many qualms estimating a linear model with count data. That's just me.
The variable $replicated_{it}$ equals 1 when a paper is replicated, 0 otherwise. The "0 otherwise" must be strictly adhered to in this setting. Put differently, $replicated_{it}$ "switches on" (i.e., changes from 0 to 1) in the first full year following a replication (treatment) and all years after, whereas the "control" papers remain consistently 0 in all years. With respect to time, there is no "before" versus "after" for the non-replicated papers. We cannot define the "after" periods for the subset of controls given the staggered nature of the replication patterns. Replications may occur in widely different years. There is no single point in time defining post-treatment.
I actually want you to take a very, very close look at the last column in your data frame. The time dummy, as you have defined it, is actually $replicated_{it}$, as I have defined it. It varies across papers and years; it should have $i$ and $t$ subscripts (i.e., $time_{it}$). It changes from 0 to 1 for treated papers' respective "after" periods, 0 otherwise. Note how $replicate_i \times time_{it} = time_{it}$, which means the interaction term is completely redundant. The treatment variable $replicated_{it}$ is already defined as per your last column. Given this information, you can actually get the most spartan model up and running with very little work on your part. Simply regress citations on dummies for all papers, dummies for all years, and the time (treatment) dummy in last column, which just happens to be $replicated_{it}$. If not obvious, the "interaction term" is implicit in the coding of $replicated_{it}$. It's equal to 1 for "treated" (replicated) studies in their respective "after" (post) periods. I go into rigorous detail regarding the coding of this type of treatment variable here.
Your supervisor's suggestion to start with estimating a "simple" staggered DiD does not mean, at least to me, to run the ordinary interaction model. That assumes the subset of treated papers were all replicated in the same year. Instead, your supervisor was more than likely advising you to start by estimating a two-way fixed effects (TWFE) regression as outlined above, which is just a generalization of the "canonical" DiD equation. Despite its popularity in non-experimental settings, TWFE comes with its own set of problems. Econometric scholarship has demonstrated ad nauseam that TWFE estimates do not always results in a neat "weighted average" of unit-level treatment effects. TWFE regressions will invariably make both comparisons between replicated and not-yet-replicated papers (those good, "clean" comparisons you want) as well as comparisons between papers who are both already-replicated (those bad, "forbidden" comparisons you don't want). In short, TWFE can severely misbehave in the presence of heterogeneous treatment effects, where the weighted average of the many smaller DiD comparisons (some of which are forbidden comparisons) result in an odd, sometimes "negative" weighting scheme.
It seems to me that your supervisor is recommending you compare the methods of old with those of Callaway and Sant'Anna (2021). This seems fine to me and a pursuit worth exploring. Just get the coding of that treatment variable correct and it's smooth sailing.

Thanks a lot for your answer, now it's clearer for me. Just one last question, these type of models (Generalized DiD) can be shown graphically? Or, if I want to show a graph for this, would I have to do an Event Study?

Correct. The event study framework is one of the most common ways to present results graphically. Typically, what you do is plot the coefficients on the leads and lags of the main treatment variable. Try subtracting year from rep_year and some of the work will be done for you. That new column will tell you how many time periods each treated paper is from their immediate (first) replication year. Just remember that those true control papers (i.e., the "never replicated") remain always 0.
